# Handling a Redirect Response in flutter after a successful Login

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I handle the following response which has a redirect after a successful login to the application where the user is supposed to be navigated to the home screen?
Here's the response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "login": {
            "api_key": "S09PJl90ajt-Nw==",
            "status": "ACTIVATED",
            "access_level": "CUSTOMER"
        },
        "redirect": "/index/",
        "session": "QHp2ajdsan07N31wMD9CMyJvaGNdYUo3Y3w9ZUZyL0dXbCZobU8-XXZpMlpUJmc2P0RKQ2hofX5FU2U7OD1NXlJEZGdoKUY2JHxNUihGWTBrVWciUUM0d3RLJ0xWJ19jMipENnBUbTJRSCtwenFQKkN-OW1cengkUHp9cmVbRHR0NSJMJnAhN3Z2NHJTLk5IdUVkd2gk"
    },
    "action_id": 1370,
    "response_status": "00",
    "overall_status": "00",
    "last_response": "Login Success",
    "sec_hash": "GEGFDzuwuCMT2Vs7m0CTtiI5XZl0Z9OXzI9HXFL-5TE="
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be something like this:

```
if(variableName["last_response"] == "Login Success"){
   Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('your class/widget');
}
```